# Apache cannot write to directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I am using an Amazon EC2 server for hosting my sites. I've setup apache to run as the user ec2-user. I've chown'ed and chmod'ed all the directories starting from /var.

As you can see below:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  21 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Oct 24 10:55 var

drwxrwxr-x.  8 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Nov  2 20:23 www
```

both /var & /var/www are owned by ec2-user.

This is the output of ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache)'

```
root      5152     1  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5154  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5155  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5156  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5157  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5158  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5159  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5160  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5163  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5164  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5165  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5166  5152  0 02:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

ec2-user  5182  5055  0 02:57 pts/1    00:00:00 egrep --color=auto (httpd|apach )
```

But I am still getting a permissions denied error. What am I doing wrong? I am at my wits end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

[Edit]: 
I tried doing a simple file_put_contents to test the permissions and I am getting the following error:
 failed to open stream: Permission denied [file]

[Edit2}:
I even tried changing all permissions on the directories (all the way up to /var) to 777, still getting the same error.

Comment: So what is the full error message?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Selinux -- the dot in `drwxr-xr-x.`  says there is more to your permissions problem than you think - you have to use Selinux to let ec-user in to those directories, too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It definitely looks to be Selinux related. But the thing is that I tried disabling Selinux, but then the AWS EC2 server wouldn't let me ssh into it. I've posted to the AWS forums and also to linuxquestions but I have yet to get an answer. If I re-enable Selinux, I can ssh into the server, but if I disable it, I cannot. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: I don't know but I am guessing that the file context for the directory /www and /var directories does not allow httpd_t.  Consider fixing that rather than something else.  sestatus -v will show you why ssh does not work: check the /usr/sbin/sshd line.  Disabling selinux on an internet facing server is not a great idea anyway.